# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax near

Tags: php, mysql

So I  was getting this error then I enlosed the column names in the backtick character and the error was resolved, my query looked something like this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO camera (type, company, model, tvl, range, ir, mrp, price, warranty, image)
VALUES
('$ftype','$fcompany','$fname','$ftvl','$frange','$fir','$mrp','$price','$fwarranty','$pathAndName')";
```

And now it looks something like this and is working fine

```
$sql="INSERT INTO camera (`type`, `company`, `model`, `tvl`, `range`, `ir`, `mrp`, `price`, `warranty`, `image`)
VALUES
('$ftype','$fcompany','$fname','$ftvl','$frange','$fir','$mrp','$price','$fwarranty','$pathAndName')";
```

Now I figured out that I was getting this error because I was using some keyword in my query, my question is which keyword was causing this error, was it range? I tried the query without using the range column but still I was getting the same error.

Comment: Reserved words are documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). A bigger problem is that you're building a query from a string, which can expose you to SQL Injection. Please see [here](http://bobby-tables.com/) for more information, and look into using PDO or mysqli.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Thanks for the link, it was range only

Comment: Try to modify this query, it's way far from safe. Sql Injection is quite easy to insert into your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the same mistake all new PHP users do - **you aren't reading the error message**. 
For some reason you notice only the fact of the error, but read no description (and post no description as well).

While the text of the error message is a key.

Speaking of mysql errors - they include a part of SQL, starting **after** the erroneous spot.So - all you need is to look at the place right before the query part cited in the error message